# Create Printer Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

Am having major difficulties getting a script I am working on to to successfully create a Printer.  I have so far managed to get the Printer Ports created successfully but it always errors with the Printer creation.

The CSV file where it is picking the information up from looks like this:

```
PrinterName,PrinterPort,IPAddress,Location,Comment,PrintDriver,
Testprint1,Testport1,10.10.10.10,IT_Test,Test_1,HP LaserJet 4200 PCL 5e,
```

The error message I get is this:

```
Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Generic failure "
At C:\myversion.ps1:53 char:19
+ $objNewPrinter.Put <<<< () 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The code I am using is this:

```
trap { $error[0].Exception | get-member } $objNewPrinter.Put()

Write-Host ("`tCreating " + $strPrinterName.Count + " Printer's`t") 
$objPrint = [WMICLASS]"\\timvista\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_Printer"   
$objPrint.psbase.scope.options.EnablePrivileges = $true 

## Loop through and create each printer 
For($i=0; $i -lt $PrinterName.count; $i++) 
{ 
$objNewPrinter = $objPrint.createInstance() 
$objNewPrinter.DeviceID = $PrinterName[$i] ## This is the printer name 
$objNewPrinter.DriverName = $PrintDriver[$i] 
$objNewPrinter.PortName = $PrinterPort[$i] 
$objNewPrinter.Location = $Location[$i] 
$objNewPrinter.Comment = $Comment[$i] 
$objNewPrinter.ShareName = $PrinterName[$i] 
$objNewPrinter.Put() 
$objPrint
## Add Security group 
## Not completed yet 
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts about what a generic failure is and how to go about troubleshooting it?

Answer (score 1):

Tim, the `Generic failure` error is raised when bad parameters are passed to a WMI method, so two advices, first try using a real port name not `Testport1` and check for the DriverName must be the exact name of a existing driver.

Comment: Is there a way via powershell to list the exact name of an existing print driver?  So far I have been using the Driver tab in the Server Properties section of the Printer Control Panel applet.  I will also run the test for the real printer names we will be using.

Comment: `$Class = "win32_printer"
Get-WmiObject -class $Class | ft name, drivername -auto`